# How to get the job id back immediately after setting the concurrency limit

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

The problem is, after I set the concurrency limit (for example the limit is 2), when the 3rd request coming in, the job execution will not be returned by the job launcher (The job launcher is blocking the new job execution). In other words, I want to get the job id as soon as I get the request by running the "runFun()" method.

I tried both the SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and SimpleThreadPoolTaskExecutor, both of them are not working. And because of the hanging "jobLauncher.run()" method, the before job listener also doesn't have the job id information. I went through the source code (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(), ConcurrencyThrottleSupport.beforeAccess()), have no luck to solve this problem.

In this situation, how can I get the job id back immediately when then job launcher run the execution?

I post the main code as following:

```
**//Config:**

<bean id="jobLauncher"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
            <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="2"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sampleservice.persist.datasource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobOperator" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
    <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer"/>
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobRegistry" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry"></bean>


**//Code:**

    Private Long runFun() {
    new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addLong("pId", parameterDO.getPId())
                    .toJobParameters();

                try {
                    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(bulkDownloadJob, params);

    //the job execution id will be blocked with status "STARTING" in the batch metadata table until the job is actually started with status "STARTED"
                    return jobExecution.getId();  
    } catch ...
```

}

After thinking, I am trying to create a new job launcher which creates a new thread for executing the job specifically and return the jobExecution right away:

```
//NewLauncherClass
public JobExecution run(final Job job, final JobParameters jobParameters) {

    ... 

    jobExecution = jobRepository.createJobExecution(job.getName(), jobParameters);

        try {
            return jobExecution;
        } finally {
            if (jobExecution != null) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        executeJob(jobExecution, job, jobParameters);
                    }
                }).start();
            } else {
                logger.error("*****");
            }
        }

    }

    //added this method for executing the job
    private void executeJob(final JobExecution jobExecution, final Job job, final JobParameters jobParameters) {
        try {
            logger.info("***** test bulk *****  Job " + jobExecution.getId() + " is going to be executed");

            taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do won't work with the `SimpleJobLauncher`.  The issue is that the `TaskExecutor` will block until there is a thread available to execute the task when using throttling.  The issue is that you'd have to have a way to return the `JobExecution` before a thread is available to execute it.

You'd have to do what you're trying with messaging.  The current message based components won't do this, but you could create a `JobLauncher` that created the `JobExecution` and sent it to a `MessageHandler` to execute it.  That would allow the caller to return the `JobExecution` and still have the job being in wait to execute.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks very much for your info. I am looking into the spring batch integration now. What you mean is to create a custom jobLauncher which can send back the job execution immediately and then send it to the messageHandler to execute? I would appreciate it if you can give me more detailed info. of how to implement this (Pseudo code is enough).

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your very useful info.. Based on the idea, I coded as above to solve the issue. Basic idea is I created a new thread for executing the code in a new job launcher. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: You're doing the same thing I'm suggesting, you're just manually managing the threads.